# Error con Tomcat en Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, server

Tengo un problema a la hora de verificar el status del Tomcat en mi ubuntu server y es que me sale este error, llevo rato tratando de solucionarlo pero no encuentro forma.
Muchas gracias!
[image: Imagen del error]

Por otra parte, así se encuentra el archivo tomcat.service
[image: Archivo tomcat.service]

Comment: No se si sea eso, pero el primer `Environment` está mal escrito.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Era eso y otro detalle más, muchas gracias! que no me había fijado